# Enable SSL on domain

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate

I want to enable SSL on a certain domain, but I can't see anything on it. The domain is api.conoform.com.

`
    # Fix MIME types
    AddType text/css .css
    AddType text/html .php
    AddType text/html .htm
    AddType text/html .html
    AddType text/javascript .js
    AddType text/cache-manifest *.manifest *.manifest.php

```
<FilesMatch "\.manifest|\.manifest\.php$">
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault "access"
</FilesMatch>

# Compress some files
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/x-httpd-php application/x-httpd-php5 text/css application/x-javascript text/javascript application/javascript application/ecmascript

# Enable rewrite engine
RewriteEngine on

ErrorLog /var/www/.log/error-ssl
LogLevel debug

LimitInternalRecursion 50

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key

DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
DocumentRoot /var/www/api.conoform.com/
```

`

What am I doing wrong? I get an "This page is not available" message when I visit https://api.conoform.com/.

Regards,
Kevin

Answer (score 1):

It look like SSH took over the port. This is my dump from Wireshark:

> ...........R..{U.X.S.j.....x..L]....H...5....$.+./.....
>   ...9.5.........3.2...../. .............api.conoform.com......
>   .................#..3t.....".
>   .spdy/2.spdy/3.spdy/3.1.http/1.1uO............
>   ....................SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-3ubuntu1

As you can see, it spits out an SSH header. Putty (my SSH client) works on port 443. You might want to look at your SSH configuration.